# Rounding using regular expressions

Tags: regex, decimal

Is it possible to use a regular expression to perform rounding on a number? The problem is that I've got a lot of numbers to more than 2 decimal places in a file and I need to move them to 2 decimal places.

It's in source file so ideally I'd like to use Visual Studio's find and replace, but I'm not against the idea of writing a script to run on the file (treating it as plain text) if regex doesn't have the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it with regexes alone, as Ryan pointed out, but you can use regexes to find decimals in your input and use a callback function on the replace operation.

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "1.234 and 99.999; .555 12.345"
>>> simpledec = re.compile(r"\d*\.\d+")
>>> def mround(match):
...     return "{:.2f}".format(float(match.group()))
...
>>> re.sub(simpledec, mround, text)
'1.23 and 100.00; 0.56 12.35'
```

The regex to match decimals is very simplistic; it doesn't match exponential notation, for example, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was what I expected to be doing

Comment: Replace in a json: cutstr='{"probability": {"neg": 0.33828654512348322, "neutral": 0.79405570286895666,....
ReplaceRegExpr('\d\d{4,12}[},]',cutstr,' ',false))
{"probability": {"neg": 0.3382  "neutral": 0.7940 ...

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can round the numbers, since regular expressions can't do addition.

You could truncate them as follows (this will work in Notepad++):

find `(\d*\.\d\d)\d*`

replace with `\1`

Comment: To do this in JS: `"C51.13333,85.23333".replace(/(\d*\.\d\d)\d*/g, '$1')` https://jsfiddle.net/v1aqbeck/

Answer (score 4):

Well... at least you can search for `(\d+\.\d\d\d)\d*` and replace it with `round($1, 2)`.

Yeah, perhaps this is not what you expected :)

Comment: That's a great suggestion and would solve my problem but I've gone with Tim's answer as I'd like to keep the code clean

Comment: Neat. With JavaScript: `string.replace(/(\d+\.\d\d\d)\d*/,function($0,$1) {return Math.round($1*100)/100;})`

Comment: @Christophe : with JS we can also use `return Number($1).toFixed(3).toString()` (ofcourse the speed debate ensues)

Comment: Beter late than never: In javascript - you need to apply the global flag for mutiple replacements: 
 `string.replace(/(\d+\.\d\d\d)\d*/g, (s) => {  return Math.round( parseFloat(s) * 100 ) / 100).toString();  });`

Comment: The above comment throws an error. Corrected version: `string.replace(/(\d+\.\d\d\d)\d*/g, (s) => { return Math.round( parseFloat(s) * 100 ) / 100}).toString();` https://jsfiddle.net/uso58hkL/

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a simple way to do this for rounding results in a set of Google BigQuery results -- their subset of SQL doesn't let you round to a specific decimal place a.f.a.i.k., but it does support regexes.

Since, as someone mentioned above, regexes can't add, then as long you can add a constant to each value somehow, you can still get the rest of the way there:

```
+ 0.5 if you're rounding up to the nearest integer
+ 0.05 if you are rounding up to the nearest 0.1
+ 0.005 if you are rounding up to the nearest 0.01 etc.
```

... etc. - basically add half of your smallest precision value to get the rounding effect.

And then run a regex extract on the result.  The above ones will probably work done for this.

Here's the regex pattern I settled on -- which is not the most robust, but will work on a number that is already known to be in basic float format:

```
+ for 0.1 precision use (-?\d*\.?\d?)
+ for 0.01 precision use (-?\d*\.?\d?\d?)
+ for 0.001 precision use (-?\d*\.?\d?\d?\d?)
```

Then it's *both* rounded and truncated.